# declared arrayList not recognized - android

Tags: java, android

I declared an `ArrayList` as follows (as I use to declare it) and then set its content. However, a notice message that I am not using declared `"al"` variable. It doesn't dissapear although I use it at following line. Content is also not set! Strange... why? Thank you

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al = parsedExampleDataSet.getView();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are setting it but never reading it.

Apparently, you never access al except to assign it.

Also, you are creating a new ArrayList, and then discarding the object when you reassign it to `parsedExampleDataSet.getView()`.  This probably has nothing to do with your error, but it's a waste.

Comment: That's it! problem comes from getter method, al receives an empty value. I will discuss it in a new post. Thanks to make me look inside...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ArrayList<String> al = null;

al = parsedExampleDataSet.getView();
```